# LeetCode keeps throwing runtime errors

Tags: javascript, runtime-error

I'm solving a problem at leetcode, view it from [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/) if you want but it isn't that important. The solution I followed to solve this problem was to reverse two arrays and then convert them to numbers, add them and finally convert them back to an array and reverse them one more time, the solution seems to work fine when I run it on my computer but on leetcode it throws a runtime error.

Here us the code I used

```js
var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) {
    var tempL1 =[]
    var tempL2 =[]
    for (var i = l1.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        tempL1.push(l1[i])
    }
        for (var i = l2.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        tempL2.push(l2[i])
    }
    var result = Number(tempL1.join("")) + Number(tempL2.join(""))
        var array = Array.from(result.toString())
    var finalArray = []
    for (let i = array.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        finalArray.push(array[i])
    }
    return finalArray
};
```

That's the error thrown in my face

```
Line 34 in solution.js
             throw new TypeError(__serialize__(ret) + " is not valid value for the expected return type ListNode");
             ^
TypeError: ["0"] is not valid value for the expected return type ListNode
    Line 34: Char 20 in solution.js (Object.<anonymous>)
    Line 16: Char 8 in runner.js (Object.runner)
    Line 18: Char 26 in solution.js (Object.<anonymous>)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Comment: The problem statement says "Add the two numbers and return *the sum as a linked list.*"  The return value should be of type `ListNode`, Arrays are never mentioned, neither for inputs nor for output.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko is this the reason for the runtime error?

Comment: I'd say yes "["0"] is not valid value for the expected return type ListNode"